# Date/Time Picker inside an HTML table (Javascript inside <table> tags) in MVC

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I have a table in my view model in my MVC project, which contains multiple entries of a data type. I would like to be able to edit all those items at once.

One of the field is a date/time type, and I would like to implement a date/time picker for the field, but that would involve in a javascript inside my table tags due to loop constraints. Is there any way to overcome this?

Here is my view model:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.A_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = item.A_Date, @class = "form-control" } })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#A_Date').datetimepicker({
                calendarWeeks: true,
                //dateFormat: 'YYYY MM dd',
                //defaultDate: '',
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                showClose: true,
                showClear: true,
                toolbarPlacement: 'top',
            });

            $('#A_Date').datetimepicker({
                //defaultDate: '',
                format: 'LT',
                showClose: true,
                showClear: true,
                toolbarPlacement: 'top',
                stepping: 15,
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: first of all, don't use @Value in your html attributes.  You are already setting the value in the expression.  Second of all, why are you trying to create two different datetimepickers on the same value?  Third, don't use foreach with html form fields, it will not create the proper naming to bind properly.  Instead, create an editor template and let the EditorFor render your table layout.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Sorry I'm a newbie to ASP.NET/MVC, would you have any idea how to configure the CSS and let EditorFor to render my table layout? I can't seem to find anything online. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have made use of a css class called .datepicker for anything I would like to have the jquery datepicker used on. I then call the javascript function like this which works on tables and gridviews.

```
<script>
    function calendarPicker() {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true
        });
    }

   $(document).ready(calendarPicker);
</script>
```